# Error deployment maven project wildfly-9

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, wildfly-9

I have this error, I have tried to resolve it but I can't.

> org.primefaces.extensions.component.gchart.GChartRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/GsonBuilder
>
> ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./csi: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./csi: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
>     Source Document: vfs:/D:/Projet/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/csi.war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-extensions-4.0.0.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
>     Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.extensions.component.gchart.GChartRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/GsonBuilder

[THIS IS THE FIRST PART OF CONSOLE REPORTING FROM WILDFLY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnKlu.png)

Comment: Have you put gsonbuilder in your maven dependencies? Have you tried Maven -> Update project?

Comment: yes, <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: Check if after update the maven if in Maven Dependencies on Eclipse your library appears. If it appears try to go to this class com/google/gson/GsonBuilder. I think the problem is you have a dependency declared that needs other dependencies. Or, is because you are using jars or other libraries  (even if in the server) and this new dependency conflicts with it.

Comment: gson-2.1.jar is here. how can find or add new dependencies? i m not using other Jars, all is declared in pom.xml

Comment: You are marking your *gson* dependency as **provided** but WildFly doesn't provide it by default. Remove the *provided* from your dependency.

Comment: Thank youuuuuu aribeiro, Problems are resolved and project is running :)) Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You are marking your gson dependency as provided but WildFly doesn't provide it by default. Remove the provided from your dependency.  ==  From– aribeiro